# desktop cube not in compiz config settings

Tags: compiz, cube

I downloaded Compiz config settings, but a lot of things are missing, including desktop cube, cube rotate and a bunch more.

How do i get all the settings and the desktop cube?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu! Just to check make sure you question hasn't already been [answered.](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=desktop+cube) Also it would help us to answer if we knew specifics such as desktop environment, Compiz Config settings version, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Some of these plugins have been disabled because the two Compiz developers do not have the time to maintain those plugins.

Rotate/cube you can install into 12.10 with ...

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins compizconfig-settings-manager
```